# I am using MVC and trying to pass value to my view from Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to pull the `fullname` from my `context` as follows:

```cs
string fullname = context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId).Select(f => f.FullName).ToString();
```

In my view instead of the `fullname` I get:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String]

Putting breakpoints in the code, I see the assignment to the string `fullname`, does not show the name but the `Microsoft.Entity` message.

Comment: `context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId).Select(f => f.FullName).Single();` Your statement builds a query, your `ToString()` is just converting the `IQueryable` to a string rather than getting the result. FullName is already a string so you want to execute the `IQueryable` to fetch that value. Since your condition expects to find 1 row, use `Single` to fetch it.

Comment: @StevePy: The `Single()` will **raise an exception** if no record with the `employeeId` value exists.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the result is maybe null or maybe more than one result,

if you want to control null returns while using EF Core, it's better to use FirstOrDefault() method.

In  this case, it returns only one result or null.

```
string fullname = context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId).FirstOrDefault().Select(f => f.FullName).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId).Select(f => f.FullName).ToString();
```

produces "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String]"

... as a result because you are using `ToString()` to get the string value of the `IQueryable` Linq Expression. It does not execute your query.

If you expect one employee to come back and want that employee's FullName:

```
context.Employees
    .Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId)
    .Select(f => f.FullName)
    .Single();
```

This tells EF to execute the expression to return just the FullName of a matching employee. Since FullName is expected to be a string there is no need to append a `ToString()` on top of that after the `Single()`. If "employeeId" might not actually match an Employee record you can use `.SingleOrDefault()` and handle that you might get back #null for the Employee name.

The use of `FirstOrDefault()` should be avoided unless you expect that there can be multiple matches and you only want the first one. It should always be used with an `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` clause to ensure a predictable result is returned each time. Using `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if there are two or more records, `Single` with throw if anything other than one records exists. This provides a guard in your logic that detects when something in your code or data state is making a bad assumption and should be addressed. `FirstOrDefault` will "hide" these bad assumptions, usually to be noticed far too late when there is considerable "bad data" in the system to address.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) to get the first element of a sequence.

```cs
string fullname = context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId)
        .Select(f => f.FullName)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

And you should check `fullname == null` in case a sequence contains no elements.